# Is it wrong to Upvote an answer on a closed question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, upvotes

I came across this question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474763/iptable-rule-to-drop-all-ping-requests-except-for-ones-coming-from-a-specific-ip

It has been marked as closed because it really should have been on Server Fault.  I upvoted it, however, because it 1) was the exact answer to my question, and 2) was the very first result on Google.  Thus it met my needs perfectly.

Was I wrong to upvote it, though?

A second, related(?) question: Should a question be closed when it's off-topic, even if it wins the SEO battle?

Comment: I upvote every answer or comment that helps me, regardless. If the answer is good, then it gets my upvote.

Comment: If it was 'wrong' it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @EJP because there's no such thing as a bug in software?

Comment: So the best strategy is quickly answer an off-topic or duplicate question and than close it, so that no-one else can answer too?

Comment: I always upvote answers which solved my problems even if question is closed. It's also an information to other users that this is the best solution among all the answers. Same with downvoting, but you should always keep in mind, that some questions are old and solutions are deprecated - this should't affect negatively person, who gaved correct solution when it was posted.

Comment: @DavidWallace - judging by great questions being closed, there is a bug in some moderators.

Comment: A useful question isn't necessarily on topic. But being offtopic doesn't stop it helping _you_ either.

Comment: @VladimirF - Haven't you read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In general, you're free to use your votes as you wish. If an answer to an off-topic question is helpful to you, feel free to upvote it. That doesn't mean the question shouldn't still be closed though. The community decides what's on-topic on each Stack Exchange site. If we let SEO decide, then the scope of SO would expand out of control as more and more questions are allowed to stay because Google likes them.

Comment: BTW: Aren't questions that are marked as OT because the belong to another SE site automatically (or manually?) moved to that other site? That would enable reopening the question in its new place and tell ol' Google what the new search result page has to look like.

Comment: @chiccodoro Not automatically. We do sometimes manually move questions between sites if they're of very high quality and we think the community at the other site would want them. Since we can't all be experts on what's on-topic at every other SE site, the default has to be to not migrate every question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - "The community decides" - a very select part of the community rather. Community's opinion is reflected by voting.

Comment: @Den Yes, the select part of the community that actually cares about quality and takes time to curate content does get to decide what's on-topic moreso than those who just have enough reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 4):

No, because the answer still helped you and might help someone else. Closing and voting are for separate purposes. Voting gives answers and questions visibility (or reduces it) so they can continue to be found by others (or not). That's what makes StackOverflow so powerful - the community votes to ensure the most helpful questions and answers are easiest to find. The purpose of closing questions seems most often to be to prevent duplicate or redundant answers. That a question is closed doesn't seem to be a reflection on its helpfulness. Votes are.

I don't think off-topic questions should be closed. I've often found the answer I was looking for in off-topic questions because I search by content, not topic. Topics help the people answering, but not the people searching. I've also found off-topic questions that I have a good answer for during the search process. Maybe moderators should have the ability to add the appropriate topic tag to the questions that are missing them.

I feel a little bold posting this. :) Many people put good answer content in the comments.

Comment: You are welcome to feel bold when posting an answer which shows you are uninformed. There are always people whining because their question (whether because they asked, found or answered it) is off-topic, but you if you don't want moderation, this is the wrong site, which is the reason it attracts experts. As an aside, the scope of SO is not dictated by the tags, but tags are created to categorize on-topic questions, and bad tags are regularly killed. If you find a question which is mistagged or needs other clarification, you are welcome and encouraged to rectify that situation.